# Let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable with $\nabla f(x)=0$ for all $x\in M$, then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2<1\}\setminus\{(x,0)\in \mathbb R^2, x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable with $\nabla f(x)=0$ for all $x\in M$, then $f$ is constant.

I guess that this statement is true, but I don't know how to prove it. I guess the mean-value theorem can help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a picture and you see that $M$ is two "half circles" which is not connected. Let $f$ have different constant value on every half circle to get a counterexemple.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. Take$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }y>0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$